# Is the Composer Version Number Unambiguous?

Tags: php, composer-php

Displaying the composer version like:

```
$ composer.phar -V
Composer version e33aebc
```

Shows some string I assume of is a shortened git SHA-1 hash.

Is that version number/string unambiguous for now and in the future?

Comment: Reference: [composer.phar /.lock with build revision information](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1502)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is. Use full hash in version information of dev phars, fixes #1502.

Answer (score 0):

The version ID there is the Git revision ID, so yes it is (almost) unambiguous. The ID you mentioned relates to the revision after this change: https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/e33aebc

So, why did I say "almost"? - well it's jus the shortned SHA-1 used by git, so in theory it might happen tht two revisions share that small part of the sha key, but that's quite unlickely to happen.

Comment: Well, one said unlikely and then it happens. I don't fear a true clash of the full hash BTW, because you need to resolve that one in the repository first anyway ;) - But this is only seven hex-digits long. I wonder why. Probably it will be automatically extended if needed?

Comment: 7 hex digits still gives 268435455 different values, having sha-1 being equally distributed this still gives a quite low risk of conflicts given the amount of to be expected commits over the next years.

Comment: Taking the first 7 digits is also a common practice. When I started with git I found some site with the probability maths, can't find it now .. only references calling it a common practice, i.e. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Git#A_word_on_commits

Comment: The probability of a chance collision is low, but since the OP answered, it has been increasingly apparent that a malicious actor can create a collision of this sort.